# Java JDBC connection Integrated Security work only from my Eclipse

Tags: java, jdbc, integrated-security

When I open jdbc connection in Eclipse - it work fine.

But when I create executable jar file and run it - I have problem with Integrated Security=true.

or may be not only with integrated security...

Comment: Can you show any exceptions or some code?

Comment: Download the latest version of sqlserver db jar. I heard some where, intergrated security was not handled in older versions!

Comment: The main problem: my progam works from the eclipse, but when I run it from the command line it can't use jdbc driver

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are talking about connecting to Microsoft SQL Server. To be able to use Integrated Security You need to add the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` on the `java.library.path` as documented on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx#Connectingintegrated :

> The JDBC driver supports the use of Type 2 integrated authentication on Windows operating systems through the integratedSecurity connection string property. To use integrated authentication, copy the `sqljdbc_auth.dll`
>    file to a directory on the Windows system path on the computer where the JDBC driver is installed.
>
> The `sqljdbc_auth.dll` files are installed in the following location:
>
> `<installation directory>\sqljdbc_<version>\<language>\auth\`
>
> [...]
>
> Alternatively you can set the java.libary.path system property to specify the directory of the `sqljdbc_auth.dll`. For example, if the JDBC driver is installed in the default directory, you can specify the location of the DLL by using the following virtual machine (VM) argument when the Java application is started:
>
> `-Djava.library.path=C:\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_<version>\enu\auth\x86`

Be aware that you need to use the right DLL depending on the bitness of your java VM (so for 32bit, use the one from `x86`, for 64 bit the one from `x64`).

Comment: you is rigth - it is about authorization. now I try to use your answer.

Comment: Firstly: I havent such dir: C:\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_<version>\enu\auth\x86

Comment: I try to run: java -D java.library.path=D:\install\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64   but it gets me error

Comment: Be specific: what error? (also there shouldn't be a space between `-D` and `java.library.path`)

Comment: I generate ant xml of my runnable file? mb it can help to understand the problem:

Comment: Error: couldn't find or load main class but

Comment: You aren't specifying the class or executable jar on the java commandline.